# CUDA installation: could not find compatible graphics hardware

Tags: cuda

I am trying to install CUDA 7.0 on a computer with a NVIDIA Geforce 9600 GT. I thought this was a supported GPU, however I get the message:

This graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware. You may continue installation, but you will not be able to run CUDA applications.

Is my graphics card not supported or is there anything else I can do?

Comment: No it is not supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your graphics card has compute capability 1.x which is no longer supported by CUDA 7 (and beyond).  The latest CUDA toolkit that will work with [that GPU](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-legacy-gpus) which appears to be compute capability 1.0 is [CUDA 6.0](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive).

The dropping of support for various cc1.x GPU types is documented in [the release notes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#unsupported-features) for the CUDA 6.0, 6.5, and 7.0 toolkits.